Besides Beard and Chuang model, any prevalent models for the shape of raindrops?
In Beard and Chuang, 1987, the famous Beard and Chuang model that describes the rotational cross-sections of raindrops in their equilibrium state.
My question is:
Besides this model, any prevalent models for the shape of raindrops?

One demonstration using Mathematica is as follows:
Clear["Global`*"];

(*Define the pairs of d values and corresponding c coefficients*)

series = {{2.0, {-131, -120, -376, -96, -4, 15, 5, 0, -2, 0, 
     1}}, {2.5, {-201, -172, -567, -137, 3, 29, 8, -2, -4, 0, 
     1}}, {3.0, {-282, -230, -779, -175, 21, 46, 11, -6, -7, 0, 
     3}}, {4.0, {-369, -285, -998, -207, 48, 68, 13, -13, -10, 0, 
     5}}, {4.5, {-458, -335, -1211, -227, 83, 89, 12, -21, -13, 1, 
     8}}, {5.0, {-549, -377, -1421, -240, 126, 110, 9, -31, -16, 4, 
     11}}, {5.5, {-644, -416, -1629, -246, 176, 131, 2, -44, -18, 9, 
     14}}, {6.0, {-742, -454, -1837, -244, 234, 150, -7, -58, -19, 15,
      19}}, {6.5, {-840, -480, -2034, -237, 298, 166, -21, -72, -19, 
     24, 23}}};

(*Define the formula for f as a function of d,c,and theta*)

f[d_, c_, theta_] := 
  d/2 + d/2*
    Sum[c[[n + 1]]*(10^-4)*Cos[n*theta], {n, 0, Length[c] - 1}];

(*Create a list of plots,each corresponding to a different series*)

plots = Table[
   PolarPlot[
    f[series[[i, 1]], series[[i, 2]], theta], {theta, 0, 200 Pi}, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, i], 
    PlotLegends -> {"d = " <> ToString[series[[i, 1]]]}], {i, 1, 
    Length[series]}];

(*Show all plots together*)
Show[plots]



@138_Aspen does my answer below answer your question? If so, you can check the checkmark next to it to mark it as the accepted answer. Otherwise feel free to comment on my answer to suggest improvements.

@MartinC. Thank you, I have upvoted your answer.

Great, glad I could help!

I am not an expert on modelling the shape of raindrops (I don't know if there is such a person on this site) - but I found the following review article which seems to contain the information you are after: "Shapes and oscillations of falling raindrops — A review" [1]. Section 3 discusses theoretical models. You should be able to access most of the papers through some judicious googling.
To summarise, here is a timeline of relevant models (there are likely others not covered in the review, but these appear to be well-cited):
1971: "A semi-empirical determination of the shape of cloud and rain drops" [2]
According to the review

Although this model describes the drop shape qualitatively correctly,
it overestimates the axis ratio of large, strongly distorted drops.

1987: "A new model for the equilibrium shape of raindrops" [3]
This is the one cited in the wikipedia link you provided.
1989: "A simple perturbation model for the electrostatic shape of falling drops" [4]
The review notes that this paper

...got virtually the same drop shapes as Prupacher and Pitter [1971
above], but the drop shape parameters are slightly different.

The review also mentions that the 1971 and 1989 models capture the presence of

[...] a dip at the bottom-center of the drop which was observed in
experiments with very large water drops [...]

which is absent in the 1987 model.
References
[1] Szakall, Miklos, et al. "Shapes and oscillations of falling raindrops—A review." Atmospheric research 97.4 (2010): 416-425.
[2] Pruppacher, Hans R., and R. L. Pitter. "A semi-empirical determination of the shape of cloud and rain drops." Journal of Atmospheric Sciences 28.1 (1971): 86-94.
[3] Beard, Kenneth V., and Catherine Chuang. "A new model for the equilibrium shape of raindrops." Journal of the Atmospheric sciences 44.11 (1987): 1509-1524.
[4] Beard, Kenneth V., James Q. Feng, and Catherine Chuang. "A simple perturbation model for the electrostatic shape of falling drops." Journal of the atmospheric sciences 46.15 (1989): 2404-2418.
